# Javadoc when extending generic class with non-generic class

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

Suppose I have two classes:

```
abstract class GenericA<E> {
    public void go(E e) {...}
}

public class IntegerA extends GenericA<Integer> {
}
```

Note that `GenericA` is package-private and generic, and `IntegerA` is public and not generic.

Now, when I generate the public Javadoc (using Eclipse), I see the following in the `IntegerA` methods section:

```
public void go(E e)
```

The problem is that a reader of that Javadoc has no idea what `E` is; i.e., that `E` represents `Integer`. I would rather have the Javadoc say

```
public void go(Integer e)
```

Is there a way to make Javadoc behave the way I want it to?

Comment: What does your javadoc say the superclass is? I just tried this on my own machine and it got the same problem as you did, but it also erroneously said the super class was `Object`.

Comment: It also says the super class is `Object` for me. But since I declared `GenericA` as package-private rather than public, my opinion is that that's the right behavior. When I instead declare `GenericA` as public, Javadoc says the super type of `IntegerA` is `GenericA<Integer>`

Comment: Ah, I see the problem then. No actual method exists with the `go(Integer e)` signature (as would be shown by reflection). So javadoc would be lying if it specified that method signature, even though that is the one the compiler will insist on, it is not the one that the runtime will insist on... tricky... I see you have the answer you need though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only way I know is override method in `IntegerA` with Integer and then call super method.

```
 @Override
 public void go(Integer e) {
    super.go(e);
}
```