# What happens to type if I derive non-generic class from a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, serialization

Let us say, I have a usual POJO called `Person`. Now, an instance of `ArrayList<Person>` will have type `ArrayList` at runtime due to type erasure. If this instance undergoes serialization/deserialization through some library like Gson, the desirialized object is not `ArrayList<Person>` unless, of course, we specifically provide a type token.
Now, here is the question. What happens if I create another class (say `Persons`) as follows:

```
public class Persons extends ArrayList<Person> {
}
```

Will the type information be preserved here? Is deserialization mechanism able to infer that the type is indeed `ArrayList<Person>` and not raw type `ArrayList`?

Comment: I think desirialization will give you type information you can directly cast to `Person`

Comment: Try serializing and deserializing it, maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you deserialize a `Persons` object then isn't its class `Persons` rather than `ArrayList<Person>` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: It will give you an object Persons that is child of ArrayList and have methods such as add(Person p) and remove(Person p) and not add(Object o), remove(Object o) as ArrayList. As you said generic types are resolved in compilation time, you have no generics while runtime.

Comment: @OrestSavchak I dont think it will give methods such as add(Person p) usless he overrides the add method. Reference example :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697076/javadoc-when-extending-generic-class-with-non-generic-class

Comment: @VirajNalawade, yeap, before compilation it is right, but in runtime you have no generics, generics are replaced with chosen type or Object. Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html.

Comment: Deserialization mechanism works in runtime, it can't have generic types, it has only some information about object, like class name and hierarchy, methods signature and return type, so it will work correct, but have no chance to know about ArrayList<Person>, cause it is just the same ArrayList after compilation were applied.

Comment: @primitiveType Not sure what you mean. Do you think it should give me `ArrayList<Person>` directly?
@sprinter `Persons` is the obvious one. Question is whether this type will work around the type erasure and maintain the generic information instead of maintaining only as a raw type `ArrayList`.

Comment: @OrestSavchak So, do you mean that information about list being of`Person` will not be available at runtime? Doesn't it contradict with the answer by @ruakh?  Also, in my experience, it has preserved that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the type information be preserved here?

Yes; for example, this:

```
final ParameterizedType superTypeOfPersons =
    (ParameterizedType) Persons.class.getGenericSuperclass();
System.out.println(superTypeOfPersons.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getSimpleName());
```

will print `Person`.

> Is deserialization mechanism able to infer that the type is indeed `ArrayList<Person>` and not raw type `ArrayList`?

It potentially *could* do so, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it *does* do so; it's not a trivial thing to do. If there is a specific set of serialization frameworks that you need to support, then you should test this with each of them.

Comment: This is inline with what I was experiencing. Good point about *potentially* doing so. So, are we cheating the type erasure here? As I understand, type erasure was to maintain backwards compatibility. How does this affect that? How far is this (functionally) from reified generics - like in C#.

Comment: @akshay2000: it’s not clear what your question is about. As this answer states, the type information is available. That doesn’t change anything about the fact that you can still type cast `Persons` to the raw type `ArrayList` and add `Object`s to it, unless `Persons` overrides *all* methods which allow adding/setting elements.

Comment: @akshay2000: Type erasure means that instances of a generic type don't know what the type arguments are; for example, `new ArrayList<Person>()` and `new ArrayList()` create identical instances. This is important for backward-compatibility because it means that you can take an `ArrayList` created by a pre-Java-5 library and safely treat it as an `ArrayList<Person>` (provided that it is, in fact, intended to be an `ArrayList` of `Person`-s). But that doesn't apply here.

Comment: @ruakh That is what I am missing here. So, in my understanding, if I create `ArrayList<Person>` even pre-Java-5 library will deal with it fine (since it's just `ArrayList` at runtime). However, will it be same for `Pesrons` too? Because it's definitely `ArrayList<Person>` and not just `ArrayList` and I don't suppose pre 5 java understands what `ArrayList<Person>` is!

Comment: @akshay2000: If `Persons extends ArrayList<Person>`, then a pre-Java-5 library that consumes instances of type `List` or `ArrayList` will have no difficulty with an instance of `Persons`. (Note that even though the *library* is pre-Java-5, the *JVM* will understand generics just fine. The JVM knows both how to work with `Persons extends ArrayList<Person>` and with a pre-Java-5 class-file that uses `ArrayList`, and will make the combination work fine.)

Comment: @ruakh Follow up question. Will things break if the JVM itself is older than generics? That should definitely break it, right?

Comment: @akshay2000: Java class-files contain version numbers. If part of your program was compiled by a compiler that supports generics (Java 5 or later), then the class-file version will be at least 49, which means that a JVM that doesn't support generics (Java 1.4 or earlier) won't even be willing to load the class. (You'll get an [UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html).)